# Question in Theorem 3.4.2 Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction by Hall B.

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hello. I'm stuck at a step in the proof of the theorem 3.4.2 in Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations: An Elementary Introduction by Hall B.

**Question 1**. Why the derivative of $\phi$ at the point $0\in\mathbb{R}^{2n^2}$ is the identity?

**Question 2**. Why the unit sphere is compact in $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D$ is a finite-dimensional vector space immersed in some $\mathbb{R}^N$, thus it is topologically, some $\mathbb{R}^M$. A subset $S$ of this kind of spaces is compact [if and only if it is closed and bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem). Now realize that a sphere is obviously bounded (all elements have same norm) and it is closed as it is the preimage of a closed set by a continuous function $f={-1}(\{R^2\})$ for the function $f(x)=\|x\|^2$.

The derivative is actually computed! Call $D\Phi_0$ the differential of the $\Phi$ map. Then for $Z=X\oplus Y = (X,0) + (0,Y)$ given in the orthogonal decomposition above

$$
D\Phi_0 (Z) = D\Phi_0((X,0) + (0,Y)) = D\Phi_0(X,0) + D\Phi_0(0,Y)= \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \Phi(tX,0)+\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(0,tY) = X+Y = Z
$$

The above chain of equalities is explained below:

1. The decomposition of $Z=(X,Y)$
2. Lineariy of the differential map.
3. The notion that $D\Phi_0(X,0) = \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{\Phi(0+tX)-\Phi(0,0)}{t} = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \Phi(tX,0)$ and analogous for $Y$. If you have trouble with this step I suggest to review some calculus in several variables!

Comment: Thank you very much. It helped me remember some things. The notation I used to use is the following:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}f(a):=\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{1}{t} (f(a+tv)-f(a))$ with $f:U\subset \mathbb{R}^m\to \mathbb{R}^n.$ Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial Z}\Phi((0,0))=Z=Id(Z)$